# What is the confidence interval of consecutive subsampling

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, sampling

I have a situation where I do consecutive subsampling from an original population and I'm trying to figure out what the final confidence interval would be. I know that Var(A,B) = Var(A) + Var(B) if A and B are independent, but since the subsample is dependent on the sample it's taken from, I think this would not be independent.

Let me give an example:
We have an original population of n = 1000 and 10 groups, which are evenly distributed at 10% each. We then take a sample of n1 = 500, and then take a new sample of n2 = 200 from n1 (this cannot be avoided in my application).

Using a normal approximation for the Binomial distribution, this would look like:

1. n = 1000, p = 0.1 for all groups
2. n1 = 500, $p = 0.1 \pm 1.96\,\cdot \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n1}} = 0.1 \pm 0.0263$
3. n2 = 200, $p = 0.1 \pm 1.96\,\cdot \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n2}} = 0.1 \pm 0.0416$

Since n2 is a sample from n1 which is a sample from n, can you just add the two standard errors of the means in 1. and 2., as if they were independent, or should this be calculated another way?

Comment: The means for samples 1 and 2 are correlated. The correlation is something like $\frac{1}{\text{# in both groups}}$. Instead of coming up with an analytical form for the variance and covariance, you can fit a generalized linear model with indicator variables for groups. This will estimate the entire covariance matrix. You can estimate population proportion by taking a contrast of the glm coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My intuition would be that the expected value of $p2$ in $n2$ would the same as that of $n$ for many repeated experiments, while of course $E[p2 | n1]$ would of course biased by a specific sample n1. Since the sampling is stochastic, would this still lead to a non-diagonal covariance matrix?

Also, if you could link to any example of the suggested method, it would be of great help for me.